# Vray materials in Unity from c4d

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinema-4d

I have successfully designed my architecture model in C4D ( cinema 4 D ) every single material and color shows up correctly when rendering .

My question is how to export these renders to Unity 3d ? I want to make some thing like real time visualization. I tried baking the materials and that does not help .

I want to create something similar to this .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mJSSVmcan0

Any help plz ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cinema 4D installed on the machine, it's as simple as putting the .c4d file in your project's Assets folder. Unity will use a plugin to launch Cinema 4D in the background and import everything in a format Unity can use (it will even automatically update if you modify the .c4d file).

Comment: That does not work ! I want to export the same view show inside c4d and i could not find any thing helpful in this